# WPF Table of FileInfo

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm relatively new to c# and WPF and am I struggling with getting a list of file information to display. Below is the code I'm using. I have tested that the collection is populating with the correct information but I just can't get it to display in a table.

Here is the XAML code I'm trying to use to display the collection

```
<ListView Name="lvFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding allFileList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="160" Header="File Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="160" Header="File Path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FilePath}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="160" Header="Date Created" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateCreated}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="File Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileSize}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Here is the code-behind that I'm using to create the collection

```
    public partial class FilePanel : UserControl
    {

        public class FileList
        {
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string FilePath { get; set; }
            public string DateCreated { get; set; }
            public string FileSize { get; set; }

            public FileList()
            {
                
            }
        }

        public static class FileSizeFormatter
        {
            static readonly string[] suffixes = { "Bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };

            public static string FormatSize(Int64 bytes)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                decimal number = (decimal)bytes;
                while (Math.Round(number / 1024) >= 1)
                {
                    number = number / 1024;
                    counter++;
                }
                return string.Format("{0:n1}{1}", number, suffixes[counter]);
            }
        }

        public FilePanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<FileList> allFileList = new ObservableCollection<FileList>();

            var searchPath = @"C:\Users\";

            FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(searchPath).GetFiles("*", new EnumerationOptions
            {
                IgnoreInaccessible = true,
                RecurseSubdirectories = true
            });

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                var fileSize = FileSizeFormatter.FormatSize(file.Length);
                allFileList.Add(new FileList
                {
                    FileName = file.Name,
                    FilePath = file.DirectoryName,
                    DateCreated = file.CreationTime.ToShortDateString(),
                    FileSize = fileSize
                });
            }

            lvFiles.DataContext = allFileList;

        }
    }
```

I've tried DataContext = this and just putting this information into a grid instead of a listview but nothing ever displays.

Comment: lvFiles.ItemsSource = allFileList;

Answer (score -1):

Had to use lvFiles.ItemsSource instead of lvFiles.DataContext